# css calc number division

Tags: css, percentage, multiplication, calc

If I use a calculator, `2/3` is `0.6666666667` which is about `67%`. However if I try to do the same thing with css calc I get an error.

```
width: calc(2 / 3);
```

Is there a working way for this?

I don't think it looks that good writing it like `0.666666666667`. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You might need to use a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: try with  `width: calc(100% * 2 / 3);`

Comment: I tried with less,css-precompilers and it works fine.It automatically give the calculated value  div#header {
    width: calc(2 / 3);
}  compiled to  div#header {
  width: calc(0.6666666666666666);
} try here http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

Comment: The output with a preprocessor is still a rounded number. I will go with one of the other solutions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is with `calc(2 / 3)` you will just get a number without an unit. CSS can't display just a number as width. This would be like if you set `width: 3` which obviously doesn't work.

If you want the percentage you will need to muliply it by 100%

```
width: calc(2 / 3 * 100%);
```

and if you really want the result in pixels multiply it by 1px

```
width: calc(2 / 3 * 1px);
```

Comment: Great answer! Then to add a unit, we need to multiply it with 1 and the unit suffix. Because 100% is the same as 1 we multiply with 100 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
```

As far as I know CSS calc doesn't convert fractions to percentages.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I think this should work as well, just for this case:

```
width: calc(200% / 3);
```

Yet untested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply by `100` to convert it into `%`

```css
div{
  background-color: red;
  width: calc( (2/3)*100% );
  
}
```

```html
<div>yeah</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have **no units defined**, and the **width of a certain element cannot be unitless**. You would need to convert the width into pixels, percentages or similar unit.

For example:

```
width: calc(100px / 2) // the result will be pixels
width: calc(100% / 2) // the result will be in percentages
width: calc(100 / 2 * 1px) // the result will be in pixels
```

There is a great article explaining the **calc()** function [here](https://kolosek.com/css-calc/).